# Interpretation of Z-Transform as discrete version of Laplace-Transformation

Tags: fourier-transform, laplace-transform, z-transform

I have a question about the relationship between Laplace and Z transformations. By definition Laplace transformation maps signals in the continuous time range
modeled as functions $f:[0,\infty[ \to \mathbb{C}$ onto the complex-valued
frequence space via

$$ f \mapsto \mathcal{L} \{f\}(s) := \int_{0}^{\infty} f(t)e^{-st} dt $$

The (unilateral) Z-transformation on the other hand maps a signal in the
discrete time domain described by a sequence $(x[k])_{k \in \mathbb{N}$ 
($k=0,1,2...$ forms a sampling sequence) via

$$  x[k] \mapsto X(z) = Z\{x[k]\} := \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x[k] \cdot z^{-k} $$

Now the philosophy is that Z-Trafo is the "discrete version" of the Laplace
transformation. What is not clear to me, however, is the exact reason why in
Laplace transformation the argument $s$ is exponated to $e^{-st}$, while for the
argument $z$ in Z-transformation that's not the case?

Wouldn't it be more natural for sake of compatibility to define the
Z-transformation $X(z)$ via $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x[k] \cdot e^{-zk}$ to preserve
structure compatibility between continuous and discrete versions simply by
mimic the continuous Laplace transformation?

Or is there a deeper reason involved?

I found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158630/relationship-between-the-z-transform-and-the-laplace-transform) a discussion dealing with similar problem but the answers there
not answer my question. My question is not *if* there is a relation between
$z$ and $s$ in Laplace and Z-transformations (indeed obviously there is one: that's
the substitution $z= e^{sT}$ as stated there), but *why* this transformation
should be imposed there.

If we keep on the philosophy that Z-transformation should be the discrete analoga
of the Laplace transformation why not define
$X(z)$ via $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x[k] \cdot e^{-zk}$ as suggested above.
The correspondence between continuous and discrete Fourier transformations
are established by mimic literally the structure.

What's going wrong with Laplace und Z-transformations if we try to imitate this the same way?

Comment: The only argument favoring $z=e^{sdt}$ is that in discrete time most people use (or is used to use) $x[k]$ instead of $x(kdt)$. Besides that, I think it would be reasonable to have another definition for other applications